# Why does the program shown in "7.2.39 IPC::Open2" of Programming Perl actually ends?

Tags: perl, io, ipc, stdin, child-process

The program I am referring to is the second program shown in this section [here](https://www.cs.ait.ac.th/%7Eon/O/oreilly/perl/prog/ch07_039.htm). A small modification of it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use IPC::Open2;
use Symbol;

$WTR = gensym();  # get a reference to a typeglob
$RDR = gensym();  # and another one

$pid = open2($RDR, $WTR, 'bc');
print "$pid\n";

while (<STDIN>) {           # read commands from user
    print $WTR $_;          # write a command to bc(1)
    $line = <$RDR>;         # read the output of bc(1)
    print STDOUT "$line";   # send the output to the user
}
```

This program runs ok. Say its name is prop_7_2_39_2.pl, so a typical interaction with it is:

```
>./prop_7_2_39_2.pl
75955
2+2
4
quit

>
```

That is, after typing "quit", child process `bc` becomes defunct, and after that I need to feed a newline to actually finish the perl parent. Why the `<STDIN>` is evaluated to false? I understand that perl evaluates definition of `<STDIN>`. The somewhat related program

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
while(<STDIN>){}
```

does not end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After sending `quit` to `bc` it terminates which closes the reading end of the pipe. Your next `print $WTR $_` will then fail and generate the `SIGPIPE` signal that terminates the program - unless you install a signal handler for it.

An alternative solution could be to check that reading from `bc` after you've sent something to it succeeds:

```
while (<STDIN>) {              # read commands from user
    print $WTR $_;             # write a command to bc(1)
    my $line = <$RDR>;         # read the output of bc(1)

    if($line) {
        print STDOUT "$line";  # send the output to the user
    } else {
        last;                  # break out of the while loop
    }
}
print "Controlled ending...\n";
```